# can you explain it as I am very much new in angular.why private todoItems: TodoItem[] = [] .TodoItem is an array which is return but =[] means?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

//It is todoList class//

todoItems is property name and array of TodoItem objects coming from TodoItem file but can't get it private todoItems: TodoItem[] = [] ?is it Dependency Injection ? can I declare like that?

```
constructor(public user: string, private todoItems: TodoItem[] = []) {
// no statements required
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Explanation of the second parameter of the function (`private todoItems: TodoItem[] = []`)

`private` : the parameter is also a property of the object. The visibility is set to `private`.

`todoItems` : the name of the parameter/variable.

`: TodoItem[]` : parameter of type array of `TodoItem`.

`= []` : is initialized as an empty array if the parameter is not given when calling the constructor.